# Excel VBA error 424 calling sub

Tags: vba, excel

I've scoured the internet but I can't seem to find an answer to my question, according to the answers I've seen I shouldn't have a problem.

A lot of the code is sloppy since it's a copy pasta from something that used to work. Intention was to clean up after it being functional.

Im passing 7 strings to a sub from my userform, but I keep getting the 424 error.

From the userform:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Bericht As Variant

Dim RuilingOfVermissing As String
Dim Benaming As String
Dim NSN As String
Dim Aantal As String
Dim Bijzonderheden As String
Dim DatumIn As String
Dim Naam As String


'Check verplichte velden
If OptionButton1.Value = False And OptionButton2.Value = False Then
    Bericht = MsgBox("Selecteer Ruiling of Vermissing", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ErrorExit
ElseIf OptionButton1.Value = True And OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    Bericht = MsgBox("Selecteer Ruiling OF Vermissing, niet allebei", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ErrorExit
ElseIf OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    RuilingOfVermissing = "Ruiling"
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    RuilingOfVermissing = "Vermissing"
End If


If Len(TextBox2 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    Bericht = MsgBox("Vul een benaming in", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ErrorExit
ElseIf Len(TextBox3 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    Bericht = MsgBox("Vul een NSN in", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ErrorExit
ElseIf Len(TextBox4 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    Bericht = MsgBox("Vul een aantal in", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ErrorExit
ElseIf Len(TextBox5 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    Bericht = MsgBox("Vul een 'datum in' in", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ErrorExit
ElseIf Len(TextBox9 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    Bericht = MsgBox("Vul je naam in", vbOKOnly)
    GoTo ErrorExit
End If

'Niet verplicht veld ("bijzonderheden") aanpassen naar spatie om Null te voorkomen
If Len(TextBox7 & vbNullString) = 0 Then
    TextBox7.Text = "-"
End If

Benaming = TextBox2.Text
NSN = TextBox3.Text
Aantal = TextBox4.Text
Bijzonderheden = TextBox7.Text
DatumIn = TextBox5.Text
Naam = TextBox9.Text

RuilVernis.schrijven RuilingOfVermissing, Benaming, NSN, Aantal, Bijzonderheden, DatumIn, Naam

ErrorExit:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

From the called sub:

```
Sub schrijven(Optional RuilingOfVermissing As String, _
Optional Benaming As String, _
Optional NSN As String, _
Optional Aantal As String, _
Optional Bijzonderheden As String, _
Optional DatumIn As String, _
Optional Naam As String)

Dim Nextrow As Variant

Sheets("Database").Select

Nextrow = Sheets("Database").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Nextrow) = Nextrow.Text
Sheets("Database").Range("B" & Nextrow) = RuilingOfVermissing
Sheets("Database").Range("C" & Nextrow) = Benaming
Sheets("Database").Range("D" & Nextrow) = NSN
Sheets("Database").Range("E" & Nextrow) = Aantal
Sheets("Database").Range("F" & Nextrow) = Bijzonderheden
Sheets("Database").Range("G" & Nextrow) = DatumIn
Sheets("Database").Range("I" & Nextrow) = Naam

Sheets("Start").Select

Unload UserForm1
UserForm1.Show

Save

End Sub
```

When I run the 424 points to:

```
RuilVernis.schrijven RuilingOfVermissing, Benaming, NSN, Aantal, Bijzonderheden, DatumIn, Naam'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the code until you're sure that's the exact line it fails and then looking at the locals (variables) window to find out what is undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you declare `Nextrow` as a vriant

```
Dim Nextrow As Variant
```

You assign `Nextrow` a numeric value.  `Nextrow` is now effectively a number.

```
Nextrow = Sheets("Database").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

Since numeric values do not have a `Text` property, the 424 error is raised.

```
Sheets("Database").Range("A" & Nextrow) = Nextrow.Text
```

Comment: Good catch, I think that's it. Error is raising from the Userform on the function call to `schrijven`, but the error actually occurs within that function, for reason you indicate.

Comment: I've tried commenting out the line using `nextrow.text`, and commented out all mentions of my previous workaround (using a `nextrow` duplicate) to no avail. Any other ways I can see if this is the problem?

Comment: @Joren it is most definitely  a problem.  If you link a sample workbook to me using a service like Google Drive,Google DOcs, FileHippo or DropBox, I'll debug it for you.

Comment: It actually worked! I found a typo I added later elsewhere, after simplifying further I got it to work. Yours was definitely the answer to the problem I've had from the start. Thanks!